# vs code react-native lint conflict

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I am using VS Code to create react native app, I have ESLint plugin installed, but not prettier.

React-native init give me`"react-native": "0.60.4"`, it is using `"@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5"`.

There is a lot of conflict between prettier and eslint recommendation fixes, for example single quote by prettier and double qoute by eslint.

What can I do to have this fix? `"@react-native-community/eslint-config"` should have solve it?

---

Don't know why react-native team put this in, with little or no documentation, I use the airbnb, eslint and prettier instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [eslint-plugin-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier) and [eslint-config-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier) to disable all the stylistic rules that ESLint is modifying.

Answer (score -2):

Clone the [.eslintrc.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/react-native/master/packages/eslint-config-react-native-community/index.js) from @react-native-community and comment the lines of the rules that you're having trouble. In my case are those:

Line 115:

// 'comma-dangle': [1, 'always-multiline'], // allow or disallow trailing commas

And line 252:

// quotes: [1, 'single', 'avoid-escape'], // specify whether double or single quotes should be used

Also I need to install *eslint-config-prettier* and *eslint-plugin-prettier*.